# Execute shell command from ruby script

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do something like this

```
 listen_for /turn on the living room lights/i do
    system('/usr/bin/tdtool -n 1')
    say "Your lights is now turned on"

    request_completed
  end
```

but the command inside system does not run, instead I get the following message:

> Turning on device 1,  - The method you tried to use is not supported by the device

If I run the exact same method from the shell it works great, any ideas?

Comment: I have also tried to create a test.rb file with a single line of code, system "/usr/bin/tdtool -n 1" and then execute it with rvmsudo ruby test.rb but that does not work either. But if i run the command from the terminal it works great.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird one.

Try `system('./usr/bin/tdtool -n 1')`

--> notice the dot **(.)** before the first slash **(/)**

If the above didn't succeed..Perhaps you need the ('\') slash instead of ('/')..

I've just tested this on my machine..

```
system("cls")       

system("cd\\")    

system("cd c:\\program files\\mysql\\mysql server 5.5\\bin")

system("mysql.exe -u root -p")
```

Using the **double slash '\\'** as '\' is the escape character in Ruby. Hope that helps!

Comment: Isn't the double slash `\\` operator specific to Windows style paths?