# Run custom bash function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell

I want to run my own function that I've put into my `~/.bashrc` in Rails similar to how environment variables are called e.g. `<%= ENV["EXAMPLE_VARIABLE"] %>` ~ I will use it in a similar context.

I've read some popular questions on the subject ([Calling Bash commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby); [Execute Shell command from Ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302668/execute-shell-command-from-ruby-script)) but I can't seem to put them to use.

I want to call a function that is loaded in my `~/.bashrc` and return the value it returns. I've tried testing with `irb` but I keep getting no method found errors and don't really know what I'm doing.

Example function to test with:

```
#! /bin/bash

function get_custom_domain {
    echo localhost
}
```

Comment: can you put up the code in question, or a more precise picture of what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've added an example function to play with. I just added the function itself to my `~/.bashrc` and (with a reinitialised bash) it works as expected from bash command.

Comment: +1 for the profile pic

Comment: @defaye Unfortunately it's not easy to execute functions which is only readable by Bash. You can however execute shell scripts.

Comment: If I can execute a shell script then I will convert my function to a shell script. Got a solution? :)

Comment: In your script, you can simply call the function at the end e.g. `get_custom_domain "$@"`

Comment: @konsolebox what's the difference between `get_custom_domain "$@"` and just `get_custom_domain` at the end?

Comment: @defaye It won't pass the arguments (the one with no `"$@"` that is).

Comment: removed my upvote because the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question, just provide a work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad practice use function in any `rc` files [`rc == run control when bash load`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/what-does-rc-in-bashrc-stand-for), create separate `.sh` scripts and put in rails root dir(or any another) i use this way for my bash scripts:

in rails_root have `script.sh` must be executable (`chmod +x script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 -eq "1" ]; then
  echo "Starting server";
  exit 0;
fi

if [ $1 -eq "2" ]; then
  echo "Time for sleep";
  exit 0;
fi
```

and call from app i use pure ruby object like executer:

```
 class Executer
   class << self

    def search_script(command)
      script = Dir['*.sh'].first
      if command == 1
        system("./#{script} #{command}")
      elsif command == 2
        system("./#{script} #{command}")
      end
     end

   end
 end

=> Executer.search_script(1)
=> # Starting server
```

I hope this example be helpful.

Comment: The thing is I want to be able to run this from any rails app I create without having to go and copy paste in this script manually or I might as well just not bother using it. Advice?

Comment: @defaye sorry but my english is very bad. Can you more explain you comment?

Comment: I want to run my script globally (in any rails_root on my computer) without loading a script. Is this not possible? Maybe some form of `system("./#{script} #{command}")` is what I need?

Comment: just pass absolute path to you script and this should work. And yes this can be `system("./home/supastar/#{script} #{command}")` but script can be executable!

Comment: Bad practice or not, this answer changes the question to give an answer.